# Editing Windows registry, from Python, Under Linux

Tags: python, windows, linux, registry

I am looking for a Python API (or a C API as I am willing to bind) for editing Windows registries from XP to 7 from within a Linux system.

The Windows target will be a mounted volume under Linux.

I would be willing to code a library if none exists. Therefore, any docs or internals on the registry would be handy too.

Any help, much appriciated.

Comment: I don't know myself it this is possible or not, but I can imagine it will be much harder to edit a Windows 7 registry from a remote machine than it will be on XP, as the security rules have changed quite a bit since then.

Comment: It won't be remote, ie over a network and the Windows system will not be running. The filesystem will be mounted under say "/mnt/windows", which is how I would like to edit things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so you're after a hive file editor?

I wrote a `winregistry` module that does this (for both NT and win9x hives). It's not really ready for the public but worked quite well with the data I was using at the time. I'm not sure what state I left it in and I haven't tested it with Win7 hives, but maybe we could get it fixed up for release? If you're interested I could probably dump it in a source control somewhere to work on.

The document I worked from was ntpasswd's well-known [WinReg.txt](http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/WinReg.txt), however I found many flaws in it (can also chuck you my annotations on that). Since then [these documents](http://amnesia.gtisc.gatech.edu/~moyix/suzibandit.ltd.uk/MSc/) have been produced, which at first glance may cover matters better.

Comment: OK, will also post here when we've got something!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [this project](http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/). The initial idea was to recover passwords but all the tools are there to edit registry entries.

It sounds like a dangerous idea though, I would rather find a way to launch a Python script - even remotely - with `_winreg` in its own environment but it doesn't seem to be a possibility for you. Note also that I didn't see any mention of Windows 7 in their project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck, as I couldn't find any such lib. when I need such thing some years back(to change a windows image file). Also writing it yourself isn't easy and I also couldn't find any MS document describing the format.

here are some links which come up in google search and describe format partially
http://www.sentinelchicken.com/research/registry_format/
http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/WinReg.txt

Answer (score 0):

Creddump is written in Python (no C extensions) and has code to read the registry (though not write it). It may help you get started:

http://code.google.com/p/creddump/